# Uninstalling NTFS-3G and MacFUSE after upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan

Tags: macos, ntfs, filesystem

After I upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan with NTFS-3G and MacFUSE installed, both programs stopped working. So I wanted to remove them and install Fuse for OS X instead. I still have the NTFS-3G and MacFUSE settings page in System Settings available, but I cannot uninstall them because the button is not clickable.

After some little research, I found the NTFS-3G folder under:

```
/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-CA37AC69-836D-4620-AD96-0F566792C5A0/QuarantineRoot/System/Library/Filesystems/ntfs-3g.fs
```

I tried running the script `uninstall-package.sh` manually, but it did not work due to the changed folder location.

Now I wanted to ask if anyone has an idea how to get rid of them, including the System Setting entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to remove MacFUSE, you can following [this guide](http://blog.downloadnp.com/2014/08/how-to-uninstall-macfuse-using-terminal.html). So:

1. Access the root account: `sudo su`
2. Execute uninstallation scripts:

   ```
   /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/uninstall-macfuse-core.sh
   /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/uninstall-osxfuse-core.sh
   /System/Library/Filesystems/ntfs-3g.fs/Support/uninstall-package.sh
   ```
3. Additionally you can remove files and directories, that uninstallation scripts don't remove:

   ```
   rm -r /Library/PreferencePanes/MacFUSE.prefPane
   ```

   (to remove the button from the preferences)

   ```
   rm /Library/Preferences/com.google.macfuse.plist
   rm /Library/Logs/ntfs-3g_util.log
   rm /Library/Preferences/org.catacombae.macntfs-3g.DriverSettings.plist
   rm /Library/Preferences/org.catacombae.macntfs-3g.DriverSettings.plist.lockfile
   rm /private/var/run/ntfs-3g_daemon.pid
   rm -r /private/var/root/Library/Caches/autoinstall-macfuse-core
   rm -r /Users/admin/Library/Caches/com.github.osxfuse.OSXFUSEPrefPane
   ```

Comment: FYI: It seems to be '/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs' for "MacFUSE" ...  '/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs' seems to be it's successor "FUSE for macOS"